# Getting input from external files?

Tags: c++, file, input, external

I need to get very basic input from an external file in C++. I tried searching the internet a few times but nothing really applied to what I need. This would be a .txt file that the input it coming from, and it would be filled with lines like this:

131
241
371
481

I have code already to manually get this input, and it looks like this:

```
using namespace std;
//Gets the initial values from the user.
    int control=0;
    while (rowb!=0){
        cout << "Row: ";
        cin >> rowb;
        cout << "Column: ";
        cin >> columnb;
        cout << "Number: ";
        cin >> numb;
        row[control]=rowb-1;
        column[control]=columnb-1;
        num[control]=numb;
        control++;
    }
```

This is part of a program that solves sudoko boards. The inputed numbers are the initial values that a sudoko board holds, and the user is inputing the row, column, and number that comes from a board.
What I need is to be able to create a .txt file with these numbers stored in rows so that I do not have to enter so many numbers. I have very little idea how to go about doing this. Mainly I'll only be using the txt file for testing my program as I move along with adding more code to it. It takes 150+ entered numbers within my program just to get a single board, and it takes a lot of time. Any accidentally wrong entered value is also a huge problem as I have to start again. So how would I get C++ to read a text file and use those numbers as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a file for input with `std::ifstream` from the header `<fstream>`, then read from it as you would from `std::cin`.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("somefile.txt");
    int a;
    input >> a;  // reads a number from somefile.txt
}
```

Obviously, you can use `>>` in a loop to read multiple numbers.

Comment: @Redmastif: if the numbers are on a line by their own, this will read a line at a time. And yes, you can drop the `std::` part. I've taken up the habit of writing it out, so that I know where my identifiers come from (standard library, other library, current program).

Comment: Thank you this answer helped me a lot to fix my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the other suggestions, you can simply redirect a file to standard input, like so (where `$` is the command prompt):

```
$ myprogram < mytextfile.txt
```

That will run `myprogram` just as normal but take input from `mytextfile.txt` as if you had typed it in.  No need to adjust your own program at all.

(This works on both Unix/Linux systems and on Windows.)

Comment: Ok. The problem with that is that I use Xcode on Mac, so I don't actually use the command prompt to compile my code. There's simply a button that compiles and runs it for me. Is there some way I can implement this into the program?

Comment: @Redmastif: I gave this answer a +1 because it's a good alternative. It might be useful for you to learn compiling, or at least running, your program from the command line. That opens up a whole new range of tools.

Comment: @Redmastif: Yes, the other answers are the right way to do this if you don't want to run things from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Create an `std::ifstream` object, and read from it just like you would from `std::cin`. At least if I understand what you're trying to do, the `131` as the first input is really intended to be three separate numbers (`1`, `3`, and `1`). If so, it's probably easiest to change your input file a bit to put a space between each:

```
1 3 1
2 4 1
3 7 1
4 8 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would start with a different format of the file: enter a value for each cell. That is, each row in the input file would represent a row in the sudoko board. Empty fields would use a space character. The immediate advantage is that the input actually pretty much looks like the sudoko board. Also, you would enter at most 90 characters: 9 characters for the board and a newline for each line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    std::ifstream in(ac == 1? "sudoko.init": av[1]);
    char board[9][9];
    for (int i(0); i != 9; ++i)
    {
        in.read(board[i], 9).ignore();
    }
    if (!in)
    {
        std::cout << "failed to read the initial board\n";
    }
    else
    {
        typedef std::ostream_iterator<char> iterator;
        std::fill_n(iterator(std::cout << "board:\n\n+", "+"), 9, '=');
        for (int i(0); i != 9; ++i)
        {
            std::copy(board[i] + 0, board[i] + 9, iterator(std::cout << "\n|", "|"));
            std::fill_n(iterator(std::cout << "\n+", "+"), 9, (i + 1) % 3? '-': '=');
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

This would take input like this:

```
 4  5 3 8
71   3   
   16  7 
   6 4  7
  6   8  
1  9 5   
 6  42   
   5   94
4 7 9  3
```

Note that each of these lines uses 9 characters. You might want to use something more visible like `.`.